Umbrella Term/Tag for Generic Meta Currency (e.g. JB007 Hero Points, SWADE Bennies, FATE and Rogue Trader FP, EP Flex &c.)?
Clearly many games think alike, having a kind of transient points that can be gained and spent, with the main purpose usually being a meta (dissociative) way to influence events and dice rolls. But as at times happens, different systems call it by different things (e.g. Impulse Points in GURPS, Fate Points in Rogue Trader, Edge in Shadowrun). And yet it is common for a widespread concept to have a widespread term that is an umbrella even for its other names (e.g. 'skills' is an umbrella term that covers what is known as Skills in GURPS, Abilities in Storyteller, Knacks in 7th Sea &c.).
So how can such meta points be referred to as a whole, especially in a game comparison or game design context, both for prose and for tagging?

I’m having a hard time imagining the purpose for such a tag. Who is an expert in all of these things, or looking for information on all of these things? How often is anyone going to search for this without also searching for a specific system? How many synonyms is this tag going to need, and how similar are those synonyms, really?
Without an obvious answer to your question, there’s also a UX issue around synonyms switching to a non-obvious target and users perhaps thinking they’ve done something wrong or the site is broken somehow.
Ultimately, this feels a bit theoretical, and like far too much work and interference to be justified by that theoretical value.

I think the answer is in your question: meta-currency. That is, to my mind, unambiguous and clear, and how I would refer to those sorts of currencies in general. 'Fate points' comes second, but it's a bit less clear since it calls to mind specific systems that use that term in particular.
I can see it potentially being useful for questions about game design, since the many names for similar mechanics makes searching difficult. It would be a pretty small gain for the amount of work needed to go through tag all the old questions, though.

I don't think "meta-currency" is unambiguous. If I was told "In , you can spend meta-currency" it sounds to me like an abstraction over other resources - money, materials, time, effort. I'd expect I can spend meta-currency to establish a base, or find contacts, or support a network of allies. Things you might want to handle in a game but not delve into the minutiae of.

some games use meta currencies for character generation to buy statistics. Other games make time slots a commodity besides any other resources that can be expended to do things, then there's experience... all of them some sort of meta currency!
